# How to upgrading EC2 m3.medium instance to c5.large instance type?

Tags: amazon-ec2

What are some checklists that I should consider while upgrading m3.medium instance to c5.large instance type. So far I have got a reference for [c4/m4 to c5/m5](https://www.fittedcloud.com/blog/upgrading-aws-ec2-c5m5-instances-reduce-cost-caveats/) migration.

Amazon console only provides migration to old generation instances e.g 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the problem concerns the region:
"You can launch C5 instances today in the US East (N. Virginia), US West (Oregon), and EU (Ireland) Regions in On-Demand and Spot form (Reserved Instances are also available), with additional Regions in the works."
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/now-available-compute-intensive-c5-instances-for-amazon-ec2/

In what region are you trying to migrate?